# Доступность данных таблицы только для конкретного пользователя

Tags: firebird

Дали мне существующую базу данных .fdb.
Эту базу использует программа, работающая под windows.

Я к базе подключился, всё ок, таблицы есть, данные есть.

**Проблематика** в том, что одна таблица пуста.
Но с этой таблицей связано несколько функций, триггеров. И по логике она должна быть заполнена.

Но так же я вижу около 20-ти разных пользователей, и им выставлены разные привелегии.

**Вопрос** может ли быть так, что для одного пользователя эта таблица будет пуста, а для другого пользователя там будут отображаться данные по запросу?

Firebird это предполагает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похожее поведение возможно в нескольких случаях:

1. Таблица объявлена как временная. Каждое соединение (или транзакция, в зависимости от типа временной таблицы) не видит данные из других.
2. Таблица обычная, но ни одна из параллельных транзакций, пишущих в эту таблицу, не завершилась коммитом.
3. Вам не выдано разрешение на чтение, но в этом случае вы должны получить исключение, а не пустую таблицу.

Comment: спасибо большое. таблица была временной.

Comment: можно ли мне вам написать? у меня есть очень узкий вопрос по firebird. в котором возможно, вы сможете мне помочь. дайте пожалуйста контакты.

Comment: Лучше задавать тут. Я отслеживаю тег Firebird.

Comment: Если очень хочется, то можно найти меня в vk, моих тезок не так уж и много, а в городе из профиля вообще я один.